# Changing link with onclick event

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make it so that when someone clicks a link (that opens in a new window) it ends up changing the link address on each subsequent click. For example, if someone clicks hyperlink1, it takes them to page1.html on the first go around, page2.html on the second, page3.html on the third.

I've tried to get this to work using jquery and anchorobject.href, but I'm not very well-versed in jquery and have no idea how to progress from that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code you tried and let us know what went wrong.

Comment: You'd have to use a URL parameter, local storage, or a server-side solution to keep track of the index. You could also use scripting to key the link's `href` value to the page filename, if that's reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an array that has list of links like it and set new href on click.

```
var links = new Array('first.html','second.html','third.html');
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myhref').attr('href',links[i]);
    $('#myhref').click(function(){
        //do something like open window.
        if(i+1 in links)
        {
            i++;
        }
        $(this).attr('href',links[i]);
    });
});
```

Example:

```
<a href="#" id="myhref">Click here</a>
```

Open in iframe:

```
<a href="#" id="myhref" target="myiframe_name">Click here</a>
```

Use in AJAX:

```
var links = new Array('first.html','second.html','third.html');
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myhref').attr('href',links[i]);
    $('#myhref').click(function(){
        $("#mydialog").load($(this).attr('href'))
        if(i+1 in links)
        {
            i++;
        }
        $(this).attr('href',links[i]);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo on jsfiddle: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mipo/yJn3N/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any way you could provide an example of how this code should also look on the link itself? I'm having a hard time implementing it. Thanks again!

Comment: I inserted the code, but it just keeps opening up the same window over and over rather than opening up the next one in the series.

Comment: @user3061277 it never opens a window , it just redirect you to new link per click. first click will redirect you to `first.html`, second click will redirect you to `second.html` and so on. you can update that array with your prefer urls.

Comment: I finally got it working. Thanks! Final question, will this work on opened iFrames or jquery shadowboxes that require the rel property or does it have to be an external window?

Comment: @user3061277 I've updated my post. check it again. I've added 2 examples.

Comment: Again, this seems to be working but it breaks every time I try to incorporate shadowbox into it. I'm not sure if it's the rel tag or not, but I'm not having any luck. I really appreciate your help though and if I can't make it work the way I want it to I'll still use your help so thanks again.

Comment: @user3061277 I've added a demo link on this post.check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link-id").click(function(e){
   var oldlink = $(this).attr("href");
   var newlink = doSomethingWith(oldlink);
   $(this).attr("href",newlink);
});
```

Hope it helps!